# Create video file with multiple audio tracks?

Tags: audio, video, video-editing

I have an animated movie in three different languages. The picture is exactly the same for each langauge, only the audio is different.

I want to merge all these files into one, so that I have a single video file where I can switch easily between the audio tracks in VLC.

How can I merge the audio tracks into a single file?

I can use any OS for the job, but my preferred order is:

1. OS X
2. Linux (Debian/Ubuntu/Mint)
3. Android
4. iOS
5. Windows desktop

It's not really important, though, I'll take suggestions for any platform happily.

The only function I really need is the merging itself. Lightweight solutions are a a plus.

I prefer GUI solutions.

Comment: I'm thinking this may be a better fit for [Video Production](http://video.stackexchange.com/) since it has more to do with how to edit/combine video and audio more than any specific issue with computer or software.

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, you are right. I didn't know about that SE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool, to do this.

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:a -map 2:a combined.mp4
```

For all audio tracks to be in sync, the video streams must be identical.

Comment: Is there any GUI for this?

Comment: Many. I don't use one, so can't recommend any. For Macs, look into [iffmpeg](http://www.videohelp.com/software/iFFmpeg) or [ffmpegx](http://www.videohelp.com/software/ffmpegX). Or [Hybrid](http://www.selur.de/).

Comment: Cool, I'll check those out.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to FFmpeg you can use [GPAC](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/home/) for this. Its available on OSX, Linux, Windows, Android and iOS. Just install the latest available binary from [GPAC Nightly Builds](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/), open the terminal and run:

```
MP4Box video1.mp4 -add video2.mp4#audio -add video3.mp4#audio
```

this will add the first audio track from video2.mp4 and video3.mp4 to video1.mp4.

Comment: if you install GPAC on OSX MP4Box binary will be inside Osmo4.app e.g.: `/Applications/Osmo4.app/Contents/MacOS/MP4Box`